# All time i had NullReferenceExceprion, why?

Tags: c#, .net-core, telegram-bot

I have 2 almost the same codes:
It's for Likes:

```
private async Task HandleCallbackQuery(CallbackQuery callbackQuery, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    switch (callbackQuery.Data)
    {
        // This is the case for Likes
        case "post_id like":
        {
            var postData = _context.Posts
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.MessageId == callbackQuery.Message.MessageId);
            //var postData = conn.ExecuteReader($"SELECT * FROM PostData AS pd WHERE pd.MessageId = '{ callbackQuery.Message.MessageId }'").Parse<PostData>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (postData == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            var reader = _context.Votes
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.VoterId == callbackQuery.From.Id && x.PostDataId == postData.Id);
            var voteData = reader;
            // ...
        }
        // This is the case for Dislikes:
        case "post_id dislike":
        {
            var postData = _context.Posts
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.MessageId == callbackQuery.Message.MessageId);
            //var postData = conn.ExecuteReader("SELECT * FROM PostData AS pd WHERE pd.MessageId = @MessageId", new { callbackQuery.Message.MessageId }).Parse<PostData>().FirstOrDefault();

            if (postData == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var reader = _context.Votes
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.VoterId == callbackQuery.From.Id && x.PostDataId == postData.Id);
            //conn.ExecuteReader("SELECT * FROM VoteData AS vd WHERE vd.VoterId = @VoterId AND vd.PostDataId = @PostDataId", new { VoterId = callbackQuery.From.Id, PostDataId = postData.Id });

            var voteData = reader;
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

In the first time this code runs normally, but for the second time I always in postData in **dislikes** have "NullReferenceException", I don't know why :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: NREs *always* occur when you try to access a method or property on a null value. You didn't post the actual exception or mentioned where the exception occurred so one can only guess. Debug your code and check the variables in the line where the error is thrown

Comment: BTW the duplicate question explains the causes and techniques to debug an NRE in detail

Comment: http://prntscr.com/p76n4g - this is photo of locals

Comment: Read the duplicate question. The instructions are there. *You* can debug this far faster than anyone else. HInt: which variable is null?

Comment: postData, voteData, del -  because first i take info from postData then goes with this to another variables in voteData i write PostDataId to postData.Id (this also an error)

Comment: The screenshot shows that the variable *reader* is null. Did you check it?

Comment: var reader = _context.Votes
                            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.VoterId == callbackQuery.From.Id && x.PostDataId == postData.Id);

This one. 

I already wrote why it's null - because first i take info from postData then goes with this to another variables in voteData i write PostDataId to postData.Id (this also an error)

Answer (score -1):

The problem is `_context.Posts` hasn't a value...

if the `_context.Posts` contains `null` you won't get `NullReferenceException`

---

**How to solve it?**

Check `_context.Posts`,

If it's a property let it has a default value

Or if it's a field let it has `null` at first

---

If you can add more information about `Posts` add it...

Comment: That may very well _not_ be the reason.